# PL/SQL Alias for DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()?

Tags: oracle, plsql, alias, dbms-output

Simple question, is it possible to give an alias to the output function in the question title so that I can call something like trace('hello') rather than DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello')?

I would like this because I use output to help with debugging and I am tired of typing that whole function name out and/or copy and pasting it all the time.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a procedure to wrap the call:

```
create or replace procedure trace(v_message in VARCHAR2)
as
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(v_message);
end;
```

Usage:

```
SQL> begin
  2  trace('hello');
  3  end
  4  ;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> set serverout on size 1000000
SQL> /
hello

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: +1. I often define a procedure similar to this directly in the `DECLARE` section of PL/SQL blocks (when I don't want the hassle of creating a schema-level procedure).

Comment: Another benefit is that you can put an INSERT statement in the procedure to write the message to a log table too.

Answer (score 2):

Use a macro to type it for you.

I'm using PLSQL Developer and whenever I want **dbms_output.put_line** I type ctrl-D. This way I don't have to depend on the existence of a function with a shorter name. It just works whatever I'm working on.